# Shared variable in Javascript files returns stale value

Tags: javascript

I have 2 javascript files. I want to create a shared a variable that will be created in file 1 but can be used in 2nd file. The shared variable is initialize with a certain value but then updated with some other value in file 1. Since file 2 is called after the updation of variable in file 1 , I am expecting it to have the latest value but it always gives me the stale value. This is what I have tried.

file 1

```
var myVar ='100';

//assume updateMyVar function exists which will return a callback with the value that needs to be updated

updateMyVar('someKey', function(result)
{
//let's assume the result came back as someValue
    console.log("inside callback " + result);
    myVar = result;

});

module.exports.myvar = myvar;
```

file 2

```
var file1 =require('./file1');
var myvar = file1.myvar;

//expecting myvar to be someValue instead of 100
console.log(myvar);
```

Comment: where you calling `updateMyVar ` to update the value

Comment: `module.exports` exports a *value* not a *variable binding*. `module.exports.myvar = myvar;` this expression assigns the value exactly as it was at the moment of evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

Its better to define a `getter` for it.

In **file1.js**

```
const getMyVar = ()=>{
    return myVar;
}

module.exports.getMyVar = getMyVar;
```

**file2.js**

```
var {getMyVar} =require('./file1');
console.log(getMyVar());
```

As of now,

```
module.exports.myvar = myvar;
```

this statement provide one-time binding with current value `myvar`;
So, there is no updated value whenever you fetch it after update .

Comment: `return myVar=200;` <- this is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
// Use some kind of Module pattern to achieve this in a proper manner.
const X_MODULE = (() => { // Anonymous function
    this.myVar = 100;

    updateMyVar('someKey', (result) => {
        //let's assume the result came back as someValue
        console.log("inside callback " + result);
        this.myVar = result;
    });
    return this;
})(); // IIFE -> Immediately Invoked Function Expression.

module.exports = X_MODULE;

// OR make use of one of the OOPs Singleton Class Pattern
class X_MODULE {

    constructor() {
        this._myVar = 100;

        // I've kept this call just for demonstration purpose.
        updateMyVar('someKey', (result) => {
            //let's assume the result came back as someValue
            console.log("inside callback " + result);
            this._myVar = result;
        });
    }

    get myVar() {
        return this._myVar;
    }
}
module.exports = new X_MODULE(); // Singleton Pattern: will have only one instance throughout the app lifecycle.
```

Both approach will give you the exact same result.